# Datagridview cell's background image

Tags: datagridview, cell

Is it possible to set the datagridview cell's background with an image (bitmap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using the functions below:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint

End Sub
```

OR

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting

 End Sub
```